# Is there a formulaic way to get all the pair combinations for dice results?

Tags: combinations, dice

If I rolled 4d6 and get [1,2,3,4] you’d have 6 combinations of 2 but 3 combination pairs of

```
[1,2][3,4]  
[2,3][1,4]
[1,3][2,4]
```

I want to come up with a way to get this result when given the **number of dice**, **the number of sides on each die**, and **the number of dice per cluster**. I want to be able to generate the pairs, not the number of pairs. Maybe something like a cartesian product could help?

Edits:

I suppose if you have {a,a,a,a} the pairs would just all be {a,a}

if you have {a,a,a,b} the pairs would be {a,a} and {a,b}

if you have {a,a,b,c} the pairs would be {a,a},{a,b},{a,c},{b,c}

if you have {a,b,c,d} the pairs would be {a,b},{a,c},{a,d},{b,c},{b,d},{c,d}

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that this will come down to analyzing cases separately....$\{a,b,c,d\}$ is different from $\{a,a,b,c\}$ and from $\{a,a,a,b\}$ or $\{a,a,a,a\}$.

Comment: so, more generally, if you have $d$ distinct faces then there are $\binom d2$ pairs  with unequal terms.   And if you have $m$ multiple faces (faces that you see at least twice) then you have $m$ pairs of doubles.

Comment: One more case is missing: $\{a,a,b,b\}$. Then that's it. The number of sides on each die doesn't matter as long as it's at least $4$.